# Tkinter - use for loop to display multiple images

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, label, python-imaging-library

I am trying to display multiple images (as labels) to the window but only the last images is displayed

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

f = open("data/itemIDsList.txt")
ids = []
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    ids.append(line)
f.close()

for i in range(10):
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"website/images/{ids[i]}.png"))
    Label(root, image=img, width=60, height=80).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you reassign `img` in the loop, the data of the previous image gets destroyed and can no longer be displayed. To fix this, add the images to a list to store them permanently:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

f = open("data/itemIDsList.txt")
ids = []
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    ids.append(line)
f.close()

imgs = []
for i in range(10):
    imgs.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"website/images/{ids[i]}.png")))
    Label(root, image=imgs[-1], width=60, height=80).grid()

root.mainloop()
```